# Problem during the insatallation of NS 2.29 on windows

Tags: networking, cygwin, simulator, ns2

I have to install NS 2.29 network simulator on windows, for which i first installed cygwin.

While I was installing ns2 it can not detect `xorg-x11-base` neither `XFree86-base`, for which I again installed the X11 package and even installed xcygwin, all the components were installed, but still ns2 can't recognize it.

I tried to install ns2 regardless of this than after almost 80 % of installation an error occurred:

> ./sctp/sctp.h:705:error: extra qualification 'SctpAgent::' on member
> 'DumpSendBuffer'